# A working example of how to use cookie.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if you could help/show me how to use cookie.js for my example I have been stressing trying to figure this out. I must saty in advance that I am new to programming full stop so I I humble and would love a plain example of how to use cookie.js

I wish to maintain the same state on my sub menu div after page refresh. I have constructed a jsFiddle to show how the navigation works without a cookie.

http://jsfiddle.net/replacement4/nKFt7/60/

This is my attempt using cookies.

http://jsfiddle.net/replacement4/nvf3V/3/

I hope it is something simple and I've just miss understood...

Answer (score 0):

It appears your cookie values not being set when you toggle. The simplest way would be to add a callback to the toggle methods.

```
function updateCookie(){

    $.cookie('submin_visible', $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').is(':visible').toString());
}

$('.button').click(function(){
        $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').toggle(500,updateCookie);
// OR
         $('#sub-nav-wrap').toggle(500,function(){
           $.cookie('submin', $('#sub-nav-wrap').is(':visible').toString());
         });
    });
```

There's probably a more elegant solution, but looking at the code this is the easiest ;)